# Custom Sequelize datatype in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

I would like to create a custom datatype that parse a `BINARY(9)` value from the database to a workable 2D number array.

The [documentation](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/data-types.html#extending-datatypes) explains how to do it in JavaScript, But the given example doesn't work in TypeScript. I tried several things to adapt the example in TypeScript, but couldn't even make something that compiles.

Is it possible to make a custom Sequelize datatype in TypeScript? If so, how to do it?

Comment: to compile your code add @ts-ignore to the top of file. Then you can add your types step-by-step

Comment: It solves nothing, the whole file is an error. For example "class NEWTYPE extends DataTypes.ABSTRACT" doesn't work because "TS2507: Type 'AbstractDataTypeConstructor' is not a constructor function type."